# How to make a program display the resources it is using?

Tags: c#, console, cpu, ram, disk

I am wondering if there is a way to display the amount of resources a program is using in a console. In other words, the program "reads itself on what and how much of a resource it is using.

If there is an answer, can you display it? Kinda a noob at C#. Thanks. :)

I am using a Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Yes, but you don't ask the application about resource use, you ask the operating system.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: For starters, we'd need to know which operating system you're talking about.

Comment: Ok, now I listed the operating system.